# html how to insert a clickable link into a text block with PHP

Tags: php, html

My current code is like this  (line breaks added for clarity):

```
echo "['<div class=info><h4>$title</h4>
<br><a><img src=$aimage></a>
<p>$short_title</p>
<p>Location$short_title</p>
<p>Rate: $rate</p>
<p>System: $system</p>
<p>Link: $link</p>
</br></div>', $lapt, $longa],";
```

The link added is just text, though, and cannot be clicked.

I wonder if it is possible to insert a link in this block?

Thank you !

Comment: [Basic tutorial on links in HTML](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_text_links.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><a href=\"$link\">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: Where are you learning HTML? I would expect them to explain how to make a link.

Comment: Just by myself, my major is about embedded system。。。By the way, It seems 'link'(this word) is invisible, the link can be click by a open space, I found the word is white(same color with background), could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! I solve the problem by modify <a> finally

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer to mark it as such. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer